# How to distribute C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

All the literature about modules is quite recently new, and I am struggling with one core concept thing.

When I make my own modules, after the linkage process, does exists a *conventional* or *accepted* way of package those modules to distribute them as a library?

Comment: As usual, you deliver files.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you mean, raw source files, right?

Comment: I meant files. Just files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the products of building a module's interface (as distinct from the linker-products of compilation, like a static/shared library) are not sharable between compilers. At least not the way that compiled libraries for the same OS/platform are. Compiled module formats are compiler-specific and may not even be stable between versions of the *same* compiler.

As such, if you want to ship a pre-compiled library that was build using modules, then just like non-module builds, you will need to ship textual files that are used to consume that module. Specifically, you need all of the interface units for any modules built into that library. Implementation units need not be given, as their products are all in the compiled form of the library (unless they are implementation partitions included by interface units).

Perhaps in the future, compilers for the same platform will standardize a compiled module format, or even across platforms. But until then, you're going to have to keep shipping text with your pre-compiled libraries.

Comment: Can you please further explain this point: `you will need to ship textual files that are used to consume that module. `

Comment: @NotJungler'sFault: If someone is writing C++ to use some library, they can't just point the compiler at a `.a` or a `.so` and expect it to work. The compiler needs some C++ declarations that reference things in the compiled binary. These usually took the form of header files, but for modules they would take the form of module interface files. Either way though... they're just text files.

Comment: So, for close the question and point the important thing. What w'd be the approach today? Ship them as module interface units? And then link them? You will still have to produce some kind of `.a` or `.so` library, and then the final user must bundle all the pieces? If you like, please, add this to your response.

Comment: @NotJungler'sFault: I believe that my answer clearly answers all of those questions. I don't know of a clearer way to spell out what to do that I haven't already used in my answer. I mean, it contains sentences like "you need all of the interface units for any modules built into that library". There's not much wiggle room for interpretation there.

Comment: sure. Didn't read carefully this one: `Specifically, you need all of the interface units for any modules built into that library. Implementation units need not be give, as their products are all in the compiled form of the library.`

Comment: Modules are just a fancier precompiled headers. They are compiled once for compilation speedup.